# Maximum number of simultaneous requests to the Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Using the Facebook C# SDK...

Assume I want to query public data for 200 users simultaneously.  I would need to make 200 API requests.  However, with batch requests, I could stuff 50 queries into every API request; I still need to make 4 API requests.

Here comes my question:  If I create a thread(backgroundworker or otherwise) and had it query the Facebook API, how many threads could I have before it wouldn't work?  I'm concerned about issues with the SDK itself as well as the API.

Not looking for code here, I just couldn't find an answer in the documentation.

Comment: facebook's api documentation is the worst documentation, I've ever seen. Better if you try using a larger number and see if the error shows the maximum possible number. :)